# Как понять грамматику предложения «Это был огромный дуб...» в романе Толстого?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, определения

Лев Толстой уделяет много внимания **описанию дуба** в романе-эпопее «Война и мир». Этот эпизод важен для раскрытия характера героя, потому что он видит дерево в кульминационный момент своей жизни. Но вот **форма предложения** вызывает вопросы.

**[У Розенталя:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)** 4. Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит **в начале или в конце обособленного оборота** (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется: *Это был огромный… **дуб, с обломанными, давно видно, суками*** (Л. Т.).

Но где здесь начало или конец оборота?

**У Толстого:** *Это был огромный, в два обхвата **дуб, с обломанными, давно, видно, суками** и с обломанной корой, заросшей старыми болячками.*

А это оформление  как понимать? Может, не нужна запятая после «давно»?   И еще такое замечание: **не много ли** запятых в этом предложении? (Грамматика не кажется понятной.)

Comment: два вводных получаются, оценка "давно": обломанными суками, обломанной корой - прилагательные,   давно - это предикация, последовательная оценка - обломанными, и давно, и видно=видишь/и смотрю/смотри, суками. Дело в том ,что при произнесении можно играть с интонацией, это как внутренний монолог с поворотами, с догадками посреди основного текста. Обломанными давно, как узнал? - видно, возврат к повествованию.

Comment: «Давно, видно» — такая форма не подойдет,  да и по семантике это единый речевой оборот.  Давно — наречие, обособить его в такой позиции невозможно, да и запись непонятная. Не зря  Розенталь поправил текст. Скорее всего, это лишняя запятая (ошибка при наборе). Сомневаюсь, что она была в рукописи Толстого.

Comment: Может быть, но запятая может стоять где угодно практически, если это речь приближенная к монологу-размышлению, а не отстраненное повествование. Все зависит в конце концов от интонации.

Comment: Вот это да, Розенталь пропустил "в два обхвата", потому что сомневался в пунктуации. А может, не хотел ещё одну правку делать. Ведь это уточнение, причём несогласованное.